# Removing Theme Icons and Wallpapers

Tags: themes

I installed the Numix Theme Icons and Wallpapers

However I no longer want them how might I remove Numix and all it's files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the theme/icons from `apt` you can remove it as follows:

`sudo apt purge numix*`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Numix folder from either ~/.themes or /usr/share/themes